# Calculate closest snap point in angle

Tags: c#

I have a feature in which I want to return an angle to snap to, depending on the rotation of the angle. I would like to be able to change the snapPoints array to give different snap points.

angle is clamped between -90 and 90 & I am adding 100 to the angles to take it out of negatives;

For some reason its only returning [-90]

```cs
private int ClosestSnapPoint()
{
    int[] snapPoints = {-90, 0, 90};
    float dist = 300f;
    int closestPoint = 0;
        
    foreach(int point in snapPoints){
        float d = (point + 100f) - (angle + 100f);
        if(dist > d){
            dist = d;
            closestPoint = point;
        }       
    }
        
    return closestPoint;
}
```

example data -

angle = -50, closestPoint = -90

angle = -10, closestPoint = 0

angle =  10, closestPoint = 0

angle =  50, closestPoint = 90

Comment: Could you add some expected results for given inputs?

Comment: Use `Math.Abs` to take absolute value, e.g. `Math.Abs(-10)` -> `10`, `Math.Abs(10)` -> `10`

Comment: Where does `angle`come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume `angle` to be -90 <= `angle` <= 90, then this could be as easy as:

```
private int snap(int angle)
{
    if( angle < -45 ) return -90; // For -90 <= angle < -45
    if( angle < 45 ) return 0;    // For -45 <= angle < 45
    return 90;                    // For 45 <= angle <= 90
}
```

You may want to adjust for the "equidistant" values -45 and 45. If you want them to count to the higher angle, just use `<=` instead of `<`.

If you want a more generic approach to snap an angle to an arbitrary list of snapPoints:

```
// -90 <= angle <= 90 and any x in snaps -90 <= x <= 90
int snap( int angle, int[] snaps )
{
    int result = -90;
    int minDistance = 180;
    for( int i = 0; i < snaps.Length; i++)
    {
        int absoluteDistance = Math.Abs(angle-snaps[i]);
        if(minDistance > absoluteDistance)
        {
            minDistance = absoluteDistance;
            result = snaps[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In Action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x3B9XJ

But to make your code work, the smallest change would be to simply use

```
int d = Math.Abs(point - angle); // you actually don't need float
```

---

The reason you are getting always -90 with

```
foreach(int point in snapPoints){
    float d = (point + 100f) - (angle + 100f);
    if(dist > d){
        dist = d;
        closestPoint = point;
    }       
}
```

is: With your snapPoints, you get 10, 100 and 190 for `(point + 100)`.

Now, whatever `angle` (say, N) , it will always be: 10-N < 100-N < 190-N

So, your "closest point" is always -90.

With your example data:

```
| angle | angle+100 | d  / snapPoint = -90 | d  / snapPoint = 0 | d  / snapPoint = 90 |
| -50   | 50        | -40                  | 50                 | 140                 |
| -10   | 90        | -80                  | 10                 | 100                 |
| 10    | 110       | -100                 | -10                | 80                  |
| 50    | 150       | -140                 | -50                | 40                  |
```

So let's step through your code for `angle = 50`:

1. Iteration: d = -140, dist (300) > d == true => dist = -140, closestPoint = -90
2. Iteration: d = -50, dist (-140) > d == false
3. Iteration: d = 40, dist (-140) > d == false

result: closestPoint == -90

Comment: This really helped, thank you. So all I need to do is put dist =  Mathf.Abs(d) to work I think.

Comment: You don't need floating point, but yes, that should do the trick.